# How to configure cassandra datacenter in case when seed is off?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm trying to create cluster with one datacenter at the moment.

Each of them should store the same date in case when one of them stop working cluster should work along.

I'm successfully creating 2 nodes but...

They do not have the same date on them they just split it between them. I read this using command :

```
docker exec -ti cas1 nodetool status
```

and Own label is about 45/55. I'd like to have 100 on each one. Which will prevent to lose data whenever one of nodes stop working somehow.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace
WITH replication = {
    'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'datacenter1' : 2
};
```

There is my commands which I use to start cassandra:

First node on datacener1

```
docker run -e DS_LICENSE=accept -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=AAIPCluster -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1 -p 9042:9042 --name cassandra --memory 2g -d cassandra
```

Second node on datacenter as well

```
docker run --name cassandra2 -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS="$(docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' cassandra)" -e CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=AIIPCluster -e CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch -e CASSANDRA_DC=datacenter1 -d cassandra
```

The are up and running within the same datacenter (datacenter1).

I understand that only the first node is exposed using port 9042 but is there any way to expose whole datacenter/cluster on one port?

I could expose each node on different ports but It may be hard to define connection with rest api because I'll have to check which node currently visible.

In my opinion it should resolve issue with inability to get/put data in cluster whenever the first node is turned down. Or is there any better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using Docker, you can connect to these instances via Docker network, so if you're connecting to `localhost` and port 9042, then driver will fetch full topology of the cluster, and use network addresses that are advertised by nodes themselves, and if you didn't do anything specific to configure them, then the addresses from Docker network will be used, not the `localhost`.

Comment: Is there any way to handle case when node 'cassandra' will be down the whole cluster will be still working?

Comment: yes, `seed` nodes are used for initial contact, after that the rest of cluster continue to work...